# Is it possible to call Monkey tests from MonkeyRunner Script

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner, monkey

At some point in my Monkeyrunner I want to launch random Monkey tests (The ones we can get through a command `adb shell monkey -p my.package -v 500`), So I added this line `device.shell('monkey -p my.package -v 500')` to my python script. But nothing happens, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your command should start the monkey tests. However, you need to pause the script execution during there random monkey tests by adding MonkeyRunner.sleep(no_of_seconds) statements. This will give time for the random tests to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes normally it should start it, but it didn't. 
Alternatively I imported os `import os`, 
then I called monkey through this command `os.system('adb shell monkey -p mypackage -v 500')`.
Sadly it relaunches the my application. Not the best outcome.